# Re-writing solutions to differential equations as convolutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation:

$$ f'(x) + \lambda f(x) = g(x)$$

where $\lambda > 0 $.

Then, using the integrating factor method, we get a solution:

$$ f(x) = e^{-\lambda x} \int_0^x e^{\lambda t} g(t) dt$$

However, the following is also a solution:

$$ \int_0^u e^{\lambda (v - u)} g(v) dv$$

which is more useful since it's a convolution.

So my question is, is there a general way to write solutions you get using the integrating factor method as convolutions like this?

For example, if we have the slightly more complicated equation:

$$f'(x) + \lambda x f(x) = g(x)$$

for some constant $\lambda$, the solution is:

$$ f(x) = e^{-\lambda x^2} \int_0^x e^{\lambda t^2} g(t) dt $$

How do I turn this into a convolution? What about if instead of $\lambda x$ I have a function $p(x)$? It seems like it might just be a change of variables...?

Comment: Since $f^\prime+pf=g$ has solution $f=R^{-1}\int^x Rgdt,\,R:=e^{\int_c^x pdt}$, try $u:=\ln R(x),\,v:=\ln R(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the solution to involve a convolution, you can use the Green's function. For a first order equation, this is the solution to the homogeneous equation with $G(t_0)=1$. As you know, all solutions to the homogeneous solution are of the form $C y_h$ where $y_h$ is any nontrivial homogeneous solution, so $G(t)=\frac{y_h(t)}{y_h(t_0)}$. So for $t_0=0$ you have $y(t)=\int_0^t \frac{y_h(t-s)}{y_h(0)} g(s) ds$.

Note that this is the particular solution to the inhomogeneous equation with $y(0)=0$. If you want $y(0)=y_0$, then you can add in $\frac{y_0 y_h(t)}{y_h(0)}$. This term can be written formally as $\int_0^t \frac{y_h(t-s)}{y_h(0)} (y_0 \delta(s)) ds$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function. Thus overall the general solution looks like $y(t)=\int_0^t \frac{y_h(t-s)}{y_h(0)}(g(s) + y_0 \delta(s)) ds$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it, but could you expand a bit just for my case? I'm not sure how to use the Dirac delta function in particular.

Comment: @pictorexcrucia See my edit.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this question, these notes were useful: http://web.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/berberan/data/140.pdf